# Wrapper class for the shell "dir" utility

Tags: vba, file-system, wrapper

I was inspired to throw this class together by an SO question and thought I'd subject it to some welcome criticism here.

The class is basically just a wrapper around the shell utility `dir`, and is intended as a replacement for the built in `Dir$` function.  The rationale for replacing the function is that it has many more features than either the built in VBA functionality or the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` when it comes to directory listings.  For example, `Dir$` won't recurse subdirectories, `Scripting.FileSystemObject` won't take wildcards, and neither of them will filter for file attributes or sort the output. This class serves to fill that gap.

**Disclaimer:** This is essentially a rough draft waiting to be extended.  Known limitations include:

- It doesn't test for conflicting attribute or sort flags. The `dir`
  utility doesn't either, but an extension should probably *extend*.
  This gives it slightly different behaviour because the parameter
  order is the tie breaker for `dir`.
- It should probably have the option to specify whether or not to return the full path as opposed to the just the file.  The behaviour currently depends on whether the `RecurseSubDirectories` property is set to `True` or `False` (just
  like `dir`, but again the ultimate goal is to *extend*).
- The command window popping up from the `WScript.Shell.Exec` call is annoying. This will likely require some future API hacks.
- Other things I'm not thinking of. ;-)

All code other than the usage example is in `DirectoryListing.cls`.

---

**Header:** The `FileAttributes` and `SortOrder` enumerations are used as flags. `TimeField` values can't be combined, so they are a straight up `Enum`. There's probably some room for criticism here...

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum FileAttributes
    Default = 0
    HiddenFiles = 2 ^ 0
    NonHiddenFiles = 2 ^ 1
    SystemFiles = 2 ^ 2
    NonSystemFiles = 2 ^ 3
    DirectoriesOnly = 2 ^ 4
    FilesOnly = 2 ^ 5
    ArchiveReady = 2 ^ 6
    NonArchiveReady = 2 ^ 7
    ReadOnly = 2 ^ 8
    NonReadOnly = 2 ^ 9
End Enum

Public Enum SortOrder
    Default = 0
    NameAscending = 2 ^ 0
    NameDescending = 2 ^ 1
    ExtensionAscending = 2 ^ 2
    ExtensionDescending = 2 ^ 3
    TimeAscending = 2 ^ 4
    TimeDescending = 2 ^ 5
    SizeAscending = 2 ^ 6
    SizeDescending = 2 ^ 7
    DirectoriesFirst = 2 ^ 8
    DirectoriesLast = 2 ^ 9
End Enum

Public Enum TimeField
    Default = 0
    Creation = 1
    LastAccess = 2
    LastWritten = 3
End Enum

Private mPath As String
Private mSort As SortOrder
Private mAttribs As FileAttributes
Private mTime As TimeField
Private mRecurse As Boolean
Private mShort As Boolean

Private Const BASE_COMMAND = "cmd /c dir "
```

---

**Properties:**  I'm not sure if I like the "flag" properties as `Let` and `Get`. `Add*Flag`, `Has*Flag`, and `Remove*Flag` might be better.  Opinions are obviously welcome.`FilePath` is read only because it is intended to only be set by the passed parameter to `Execute` (and is probably misnamed - again, suggestions are welcome).

```
Public Property Get FilePath() As String
    FilePath = mPath
End Property

Public Property Let SortFlags(ByVal value As SortOrder)
    mSort = value
End Property

Public Property Get SortFlags() As SortOrder
    SortFlags = mSort
End Property

Public Property Let AttributeFlags(ByVal value As FileAttributes)
    mAttribs = value
End Property

Public Property Get AttributeFlags() As FileAttributes
    AttributeFlags = mAttribs
End Property

Public Property Let SortTimeField(ByVal value As TimeField)
    mTime = value
End Property

Public Property Get SortTimeField() As TimeField
    SortTimeField = mTime
End Property

Public Property Let RecurseSubDirectories(ByVal value As Boolean)
    mRecurse = value
End Property

Public Property Get RecurseSubDirectories() As Boolean
    RecurseSubDirectories = mRecurse
End Property

Public Property Let ShortFileNames(ByVal value As Boolean)
    mShort = value
End Property

Public Property Get ShortFileNames() As Boolean
    ShortFileNames = mShort
End Property
```

---

**Internal Functionality:** Just a couple of helper functions to convert the enumeration values into the command line options:

```
Private Function SortArguments() As String
    If SortFlags = SortOrder.Default Then
        SortArguments = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    With New Scripting.Dictionary
        If mSort And NameAscending Then .Add "n", vbNull
        If mSort And NameDescending Then .Add "-n", vbNull
        If mSort And ExtensionAscending Then .Add "e", vbNull
        If mSort And ExtensionDescending Then .Add "-e", vbNull
        If mSort And TimeAscending Then .Add "d", vbNull
        If mSort And TimeDescending Then .Add "-d", vbNull
        If mSort And SizeAscending Then .Add "s", vbNull
        If mSort And SizeDescending Then .Add "-s", vbNull
        If mSort And DirectoriesFirst Then .Add "g", vbNull
        If mSort And DirectoriesLast Then .Add "-g", vbNull
        SortArguments = " /o:" & Join(.Keys, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function

Private Function AttributeArguments() As String
    If AttributeFlags = SortOrder.Default Then
        AttributeArguments = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    With New Scripting.Dictionary
        If mAttribs And HiddenFiles Then .Add "h", vbNull
        If mAttribs And NonHiddenFiles Then .Add "-h", vbNull
        If mAttribs And SystemFiles Then .Add "s", vbNull
        If mAttribs And NonSystemFiles Then .Add "-s", vbNull
        If mAttribs And DirectoriesOnly Then .Add "d", vbNull
        If mAttribs And FilesOnly Then .Add "-d", vbNull
        If mAttribs And ArchiveReady Then .Add "a", vbNull
        If mAttribs And NonArchiveReady Then .Add "-a", vbNull
        If mAttribs And ReadOnly Then .Add "r", vbNull
        If mAttribs And NonReadOnly Then .Add "-r", vbNull
        AttributeArguments = " /a:" & Join(.Keys, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function

Private Function TimeArgument() As String
    Select Case SortTimeField
        Case TimeField.Default
            TimeArgument = vbNullString
        Case Creation
            TimeArgument = " /t:c"
        Case LastAccess
            TimeArgument = " /t:a"
        Case LastWritten
            TimeArgument = " /t:w"
    End Select
End Function
```

---

**The Sole Method:** When passed a file path, it performs a `dir` on it. Supports `?` and `*` wildcards:

```
Public Function Execute(ByVal dirPath As String) As String()
    mPath = dirPath
    Dim command As String
    command = BASE_COMMAND & """" & dirPath & """ /b " & SortArguments & _
              AttributeArguments & TimeArgument

    If mRecurse Then command = command & " /s"
    If mShort Then command = command & " /x"

    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        With .Exec(command).StdOut
            Dim output As String
            Dim arrayBound As Long
            Dim results() As String
            results = Split(vbNullString)

            Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
                output = .ReadLine
                If output <> vbNullString Then
                    arrayBound = UBound(results) + 1
                    ReDim Preserve results(arrayBound)
                    results(arrayBound) = output
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    End With

    Execute = results
End Function
```

---

**Usage example:**

```
'Displays all System32 .dll files in descending order by creation time.
With New DirectoryListing
    .SortFlags = TimeDescending
    .AttributeFlags = FilesOnly
    Dim result() As String
    result = .Execute("C:\Windows\System32\*.dll")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        Debug.Print result(i)
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: This is going to be **so** useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Private Const BASE_COMMAND = "cmd /c dir "
> ```

The constant declaration doesn't have an explicit type; this would trigger an inspection result with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com); applying thhe quickfix would turn the declaration into this:

```
Private Const BASE_COMMAND As String = "cmd /c dir "
```

It's debatable whether explicitly assigning the return value has any use here:

```
If SortFlags = SortOrder.Default Then
    SortArguments = vbNullString
    Exit Function
End If
```

The result would be the same without the assignment... on the other hand, it's a good practice to have all code paths return a value, be it only for the love of explicitness.

Same here:

```
If AttributeFlags = SortOrder.Default Then
    AttributeArguments = vbNullString
    Exit Function
End If
```

...except there's a minor little copy-pasta error here - `SortOrder.Default` should be `FileAttributes.Default`! ..but it's no biggie because both values are 0.

The naming of enum types isn't consistent - flag enums should have a plural name:

```
Public Enum FileAttributes 'correct
    Default = 0
    HiddenFiles = 2 ^ 0
    NonHiddenFiles = 2 ^ 1
    SystemFiles = 2 ^ 2
    '...
End Enum

Public Enum SortOrder 'how does client code know they can be combined?
    Default = 0
    NameAscending = 2 ^ 0
    NameDescending = 2 ^ 1
    ExtensionAscending = 2 ^ 2
    '...
End Enum

Public Enum TimeField 'ok
    Default = 0
    Creation = 1
    LastAccess = 2
    LastWritten = 3
End Enum
```

I have no problem with `TimeField` or its values. Perhaps better names could be `FileAttributeFlags` and `SortOrderFlags` for the two flag enum types? I have no neat solution for the mutually exclusive sort flag values though, other than proper validation and error-raising in `Property Let SortFlags`.

The `TimeField` enum member values don't need to be explicit (they're assigned to the default values anyway).

`SortOrder` values come in mutually exclusive pairs, so there should be some validation logic in the `Property Let SortFlags` member, to raise an error that tells the client code when it tries to set the `NameAscending` flag when `NameDescending` is already set.

```
Public Property Let SortFlags(ByVal value As SortOrder)
    ThrowOnConflictingSortFlags value
    mSort = value
End Property

Private Sub ThrowOnConflictingSortFlags(ByVal value As SortOrder)
    'this is where short-circuiting logical operators would be nice...
    If HasFlag(value, NameAscending + NameDescending) Then OnConflictingFlagsError NameAscending, NameDescending
    If HasFlag(value, ExtensionAscending + ExtensionDescending) Then OnConflictingFlagsError ExtensionAscending, ExtensionDescending
    If HasFlag(value, TimeAscending + TimeDescending) Then OnConflictingFlagsError TimeAscending, TimeDescending
    If HasFlag(value, SizeAscending + SizeDescending) Then OnConflictingFlagsError SizeAscending, SizeDescending
    If HasFlag(value, DirectoriesFirst, DirectoriesLast) Then OnConflictingFlagsError DirectoriesFirst, DirectoriesLast
End Sub

Private Sub OnConflictingFlagsError(ByVal flag1 As SortOrder, ByVal flag2 As SortOrder)
    'something like this could work I guess
    Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Specified sort order flags values " & flag1 & " and " & flag2 & " are mutually exclusive."
End Sub

Private Function HasFlag(ByVal value As Long, ByVal flag As Long) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (value And flag) = flag
End Function
```

Such a `HasFlag` function could very well be reused to simplify `SortArguments` and `AttributeArguments` functions, too.

Comment: Yeah, the naming part of my brain wasn't working when I wrote it... although I *always* debate myself as to whether flag enums should be plural or singular. The Easter egg copy paste error is still undiscovered...

Comment: @Comintern I would consider making Mug's `HasFlag` a public "static" method, maybe move it into a module. I personally like the properties as they are. It makes the code much less verbose than a bunch of `AddFlags` would be. Take it with a grain of salt though, I've been spending my time bit-twiddling register values on a microcontroller lately. The `AddFlag` methods may be easier for average joe VBA dev to grok.